# Moving files from various directories to one single directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell

I'm trying to create a batch file in Win 7 which will move all photos and videos from a certain folder which could be in multiple user profiles, to a single folder on a shared drive.

I have come up with this...

```
for /d %%u in (C:\Users\*) do for %%x in (jpg jpeg bmp png gif raw jfif mov mp4 3gp) do         xcopy "C:\Users\%%~nu\dropbox\camera uploads\*.%%x" "\\media\goflex home public\photos\dropbox camera uploads\" /c /i /y /s /d
for /d %%u in (C:\Users\*) do for %%x in (jpg jpeg bmp png gif raw jfif mov mp4 3gp) do erase "C:\Users\%%~nu\dropbox\camera uploads\*.%%x"  /f
```

But if I don't have a connection to the shared drive, the files won't copy, but they will be deleted. Hence, wanting to use a move command rather than copy.

Alternatively, an if command might also work, saying not to complete the batch if the destination is not available.

Comment: do an if exist "dest_name" before doing the erase.

Comment: @Preet Thank you, I've changed the second line to...
    if exist "\\media\goflex home public\photos\dropbox camera uploads\" for /d %%u in (C:\Users\*) do for %%x in (jpg jpeg bmp png gif raw jfif mov mp4 3gp) do erase "C:\Users\%%~nu\dropbox\camera uploads\*.%%x"  /f 
... and it seems to have worked.

Comment: Since you mentioned you are running on Windows 7, you could consider using PowerShell instead of commandline. If so, I have made a powershell solution that you could test and see if its doing the job

Comment: @Koliat I've never even tried Powershell, but am willing to learn... If you could point me in the right direction, that'd be great

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell

Since you agreed on PowerShell solution - as for the basics - .ps1 file is "more or less"
equivalent of .bat file you know. Powershell comes preinstalled in newer versions of Windows. It aims to replace the classic cmd completely as that processor is really outdated by now. The current stable release of PowerShell is 4.0 - you have to download additional packages from MSDN site. However the script I posted should work as it uses only the most basic commands. I'm not exactly sure about that though, you have to give it a try. I have put the comments around the script trying to explain every line. There is also a really nice blog for learners, at the Technet site: [Hey, Scripting Guy!](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/) If you haven't run PowerShell at the machine at all, I assume you will have to set the execution policy to RemoteSigned. Open up the PowerShell as administrator and write -

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

And now comes the actual code. Save it to .ps1 file or run it from ISE. I don't think stackoverflow would be a proper place to write detailed guide on Powershell for beginners, and there are just enough out there over the Internet. Make sure to change the variables to suit your needs. Also, it could be nice if you added "Powershell" tag to the question so that other users would see the Powershell solution. If you are interested in automation, then Powershell is the way to go, since it was designed with automation in mind.

```
#The 'array' in square brackets determine the type of variable. Variable is initialized by '$' sign. As we are looking for many types of objects, the array is required.
[array]$Extensions = "*.jpg","*.jpeg","*.bmp","*.png","*.gif","*.raw","*.jfif","*.mov","*.mp4","*.3gp"
#At '$DestinationDir' you point the directory to be searched
$DestinationDir = "C:\Users\"
#At 'SourceFiles' we are listing recursively all the files that match either of the extensions listed in the array (-include paramter). Get-ChildItem cmdlet is somehow equivalent of "dir" in batch. -recurse option determines that we are to look for data in each subdirectory
$SourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -recurse $DestinationDir -Include $Extensions
#The destination directory
$MediaDir = "\\media\someshare\"
#Here goes the conditional statement. Test-Path checks if the '$MediaDir' (above) exists, or is reachable. If it returns $true (the path exists), the script proceeds to perform actions in curly brackets. 
if (Test-Path $MediaDir)
{
#Here goes the actual routine. '$SourceFiles' lists all the files that matched the expression. Then, the output is piped to the second part of function. The function takes one object each from '$SourceFiles', copies them to the destination and removes the item from its' original directory. The '$_' denotes a current object that is being processed in the "forEach-Object" loop.
$SourceFiles | ForEach-Object 
    { 
Copy-Item $_ -Destination $MediaDir 
Remove-Item $_
    }
#The script finishes after all elements are processed. If the condition at the 'if' statement above is false. the script skips the Copy/Remove routine and prints to the host (console) that media is not reachable and it's aborting.
}
else {Write-Host "Media is not reachable, aborting any operation" }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Like I said, I've not used Powershell before, so I need to do further research into it, but your answer seems like a good place to start. It's just a case of switching from what you already know and use.

Comment: I did that switch and I don't regret - Powershell is successor from classic commandline and it's always good to learn the software which is up to date. And this is something I would recommend anyone who works with Windows operating systems :-) Should you have some issues or question, post them and I'll try to answer. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

<sub>**Disclaimer**: I extracted this answer from the OPs question. [Answers should not be contained in the question itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309555/316262).</sub>

---

#### Answer provided by [Jony Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3465164/jem):

Following the comment below from Preet Sangha, I am now using...

```
for /d %%u in (C:\Users\*) do for %%x in (jpg jpeg bmp png gif raw jfif mov mp4 3gp) do xcopy "C:\Users\%%~nu\dropbox\camera uploads\*.%%x" "\\media\goflex home public\photos\dropbox camera uploads\" /c /i /y /s /d
if exist "\\media\goflex home public\photos\dropbox camera uploads\" for /d %%u in (C:\Users\*) do for %%x in (jpg jpeg bmp png gif raw jfif mov mp4 3gp) do erase "C:\Users\%%~nu\dropbox\camera uploads\*.%%x"  /f
```

.... this solution seems to be doing the job correctly, but any other solutions would be useful.